# .eslintrc.js shows error: Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser

Tags: typescript

I've just migrated from tslint to eslint and am getting a wavy red underline error from VSCode on the first character of my .eslintrc.js file:

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided.eslint
```

I am able to compile successfully and get the expected linting warnings in VSCode, so I could add the file to .eslintignore, but it seems like I may need to fix something in my configuration. I don't know if there are consequences to ignoring this error. When I do build, I see warning such as ***"Tried to lint ... but found no valid, enabled rules for this file type and file path in the resolved configuration."***

This error message is unclear to me as parserOptions.project is in this file (in other words, the error message reads like two files are in conflict, but the error in in the file is referring to itself).

What is eslint looking for? I tried adding `project: './tsconfig.json'` to parserOptions, but that isn't clearing the error.

My .eslintrc.js file:

```
// https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config
// https://github.com/typescript-eslint/tslint-to-eslint-config/blob/master/docs/FAQs.md

module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2020: true,
        node: true, // to avoid flagging error on module.exports
    },
    extends: [
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
        // 'prettier', // 'prettier/@typescript-eslint',
    ],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: { project: 'tsconfig.json', sourceType: 'module', project: './tsconfig.json' },
    plugins: ['eslint-plugin-import', 'eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow', 'eslint-plugin-jsdoc', '@typescript-eslint', '@typescript-eslint/tslint'],
    rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/array-type': ['error', { default: 'array' }],
        '@typescript-eslint/await-thenable': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
            'error',
            {
                types: {
                    Object: { message: 'Avoid using the `Object` type. Did you mean `object`?' },
                    Function: { message: 'Avoid using the `Function` type. Prefer a specific function type, like `() => void`.' },
                    Boolean: { message: 'Avoid using the `Boolean` type. Did you mean `boolean`?' },
                    Number: { message: 'Avoid using the `Number` type. Did you mean `number`?' },
                    String: { message: 'Avoid using the `String` type. Did you mean `string`?' },
                    Symbol: { message: 'Avoid using the `Symbol` type. Did you mean `symbol`?' },
                },
            },
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-assertions': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off', // requires that each function declares TS type of return
        '@typescript-eslint/member-delimiter-style': [
            'off',
            {
                multiline: { delimiter: 'none', requireLast: true },
                singleline: { delimiter: 'semi', requireLast: false },
            },
        ],
        '@typescript-eslint/naming-convention': [
            'error',
            {
                selector: 'memberLike',
                modifiers: ['private'],
                format: ['camelCase', 'PascalCase'],
                leadingUnderscore: 'require',
            },
        ], 
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises': ['error', {checksVoidReturn:false}], //https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md
        '@typescript-eslint/no-misused-new': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-parameter-properties': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/prefer-regexp-exec': 'off', // warn on .match("string")
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment': 'off', //warning when assigning uxp require(), etc
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call': 'off', // warnings on e.toString(), etc
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access': 'off', //errors on use of PS libraries via require
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/prefer-function-type': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/prefer-namespace-keyword': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/promise-function-async': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/require-await': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/restrict-plus-operands': 'off', 
        '@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/semi': ['off', null],
        '@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference': ['error', { path: 'always', types: 'prefer-import', lib: 'always' }],
        '@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures': 'error',
        '@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment': 'off', // allow @ts-ignore and such
        'comma-dangle': 'off',
        complexity: 'off',
        'constructor-super': 'error',
        'dot-notation': 'error',
        eqeqeq: ['error', 'always'], // === and !==
        'guard-for-in': 'error',
        'id-blacklist': ['error', 'any', 'Number', 'number', 'String', 'string', 'Boolean', 'boolean', 'Undefined', 'undefined'],
        'id-match': 'error',
        'import/no-deprecated': 'error',
        'jsdoc/check-alignment': 'error',
        'jsdoc/check-indentation': 'error',
        'jsdoc/newline-after-description': 'error',
        'max-classes-per-file': ['error', 1],
        'new-parens': 'error',
        'no-bitwise': 'error',
        'no-caller': 'error',
        'no-cond-assign': 'error',
        'no-console': 'off',
        'no-debugger': 'off',
        'no-empty': 'error',
        'no-empty-function': 'error',
        'no-eval': 'error',
        'no-fallthrough': 'off',
        'no-invalid-this': 'off',
        'no-new-wrappers': 'error',
        'no-return-await': 'off',
        'no-shadow': 'error',
        'no-throw-literal': 'error',
        'no-trailing-spaces': 'off',
        'no-undef-init': 'error',
        'no-underscore-dangle': 'off',
        'no-unsafe-finally': 'error',
        'no-unused-expressions': 'error',
        'no-unused-labels': 'error',
        'no-use-before-define': 'off',
        'no-var': 'error',
        'object-shorthand': 'off',
        'one-var': ['error', 'never'],
        'prefer-arrow/prefer-arrow-functions': 'off',
        'prefer-const': 'off',
        radix: 'error',
        'require-await': 'off',
        semi: 'off',
        'use-isnan': 'error',
        'valid-typeof': 'off',
        /* '@typescript-eslint/tslint/config': [ //! are these just failed tslint to eslint migration settings???
            'error',
            {
                rules: {
                    encoding: true,
                    'no-promise-as-boolean': true,
                    'static-this': true,
                },
            },
        ], */
    },
};
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
    //full list of options at https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            "*": ["../typings/*"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
        },
        "typeRoots": ["../typings", "./node_modules/@types"], 
        "types": ["node"],
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strict": true, 
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
        //OUTPUTS
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2018", 
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2020"],
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "assumeChangesOnlyAffectDirectDependencies": true, 
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

I am not using any additional copies of .eslintrc.js or tsconfig.json in my project, just the above.

top level node modules installed:

```
├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint@4.29.3
├── @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@3.10.1
├── @typescript-eslint/parser@3.10.1
├── clean-webpack-plugin@3.0.0
├── copy-webpack-plugin@9.0.1
├── css-loader@5.2.7
├── eslint-loader@4.0.2
├── eslint-plugin-import@2.24.2
├── eslint-plugin-jsdoc@36.0.8
├── eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow@1.2.3
├── eslint-plugin-react@7.24.0
├── eslint@7.32.0
├── file-loader@6.2.0
├── fs@0.0.1-security
├── sass-loader@10.2.0
├── sass@1.37.5
├── style-loader@1.3.0
├── ts-loader@8.3.0
├── tslint-loader@3.5.4
├── tslint@6.1.3
├── url-loader@4.1.1
├── webpack-bundle-analyzer@4.4.2
├── webpack-cli@4.7.2
├── webpack-merge@5.8.0
└── webpack@5.49.0
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: project doesn't seem to be a valid property for parserOptions, [ESLint Language Options](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options)

Comment: Thanks, @Todd. Not sure what happened (after making other changes to node modules I thought would be unrelated), but the warning flag went away. Very odd, I don't know what "fixed" it.

Comment: @Todd the OP is using `typescript` (i.e. `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'`) and thus `project` is a valid property (https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/parser)